# In Django no other function getting called except one rest showing error 403

Tags: python, django

This is our code for url

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
    from django.urls import path,re_path
    from . import views
    
    app_name = 'challengeide'
    urlpatterns = [
            
        url('challengeide', views.qtn,name='test'),
        url('challenge/', views.challengeide, name='challengeide'),
        url('challenge/', views.dataentry, name='dataentry'),
        #url('challengeide', views.dataentry,name='dataentry'),
        url('challenge/challengeide/', views.send_challenge_request, name='send_challenge_request'),
    ]
```

this is code for views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponseForbidden
import requests
from challengeide.models import Challenge_Detail
from challengeide.models import ChallengeDemo
import json
from django.utils.datastructures import MultiValueDictKeyError
from users.models import Profile
from django.shortcuts  import redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
def qtn(request):
    try:
        #print("If loop")
        data = request.POST['opponent']
        data1 = request.POST['qts']
        opponent_row = Profile.objects.get(slug = data)
        global to_id
        to_id = opponent_row.user_id
        print(data,data1)
        global a
        a = int(data1)
        question_desc = Challenge_Detail.objects.get(id = a)
        #print(a)
        #dataentry(request)
        return render(request,"challengeide.html",{'ChallengeDetails':question_desc})
    except MultiValueDictKeyError :
        #print("in else")
        question_desc = Challenge_Detail.objects.get(id = a)
        e1 = question_desc.expout
        e2 = question_desc.expout2
        e3 = question_desc.expout3
        e4 = question_desc.expout4
        e5 = question_desc.expout5
        i1 = question_desc.expin
        i2 = question_desc.expin2
        i3 = question_desc.expin3
        i4 = question_desc.expin4
        i5 = question_desc.expin5
        for i in range(1,6):
            if (i==1):
                if request.is_ajax():
                    source = request.POST['source']
                    lang = request.POST['lang']
                    data = {
                        'client_secret': '' ,
                        'async': 0,
                        'source': source,
                        'lang': lang,
                        'time_limit': 5,
                        'memory_limit': 262144,

                    }

                    
                    x = str(i1)
                    i1 = x.replace("qwe","\n")
                    data['input'] = i1
                    
                    '''
                    if 'input' in request.POST:
                        data['input'] = request.POST['input']'''
                    r = requests.post(RUN_URL, data=data)
                    
                    temp =(r.json().copy())
                    print(temp)
                    print(data)
                    global out_returned
                    if(temp["run_status"]["status"]!="CE"):
                        out_returned = temp['run_status']["output"]
                        e = temp['compile_status']
                        print(e)
                        compare(out_returned,e1)
                        print(e1)
                        print(out_returned)
                    else:
                        error = (temp["compile_status"])
                        print(error)
                        ex = {"Problem" :error}
                        print(type(ex))
                        print(ex)
                        return JsonResponse(r.json(), safe=False))
                    
                else:
                    return HttpResponseForbidden()


def send_challenge_request(request):    
    print("dataintial")
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=to_id)
    print(request.user)
    print(user)
    print("dataentry")
    entry = ChallengeDemo(
    from_id=request.user,
    to_id=user,
    score1 = 10.5,
    score2 = 12.5,
    qtn_id = 1
    )
    entry.save()
    print("dataexit")
    return render(request, 'challenge.html')
```

this is where we are calling the function send_challenge_request in html

```
                                    <a
                                    class="btn btn-primary mr-2"
                                    href="{% url 'challengeide:send_challenge_request' %}"
                                    >Submit</a
                                    >
```

the function send_challenge_request is not getting called and error 403 Access to localhost was denied is been shown and this is the anchor tag which we using to call the function present in views.py.

Comment: what happens if you put your last url (path) first in the list of url patterns?

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/challenge/challengeide/
Raised by: challengeide.views.send_challenge_request

Comment: Only the first url is working rest and others are not being called